# Como obtener el valor de los atributos de un formulario con spring?

Tags: java, spring, controller

Tengo un formulario, en el cual quiero recuperar los valores ingresados en los campos, tengo el siguiente codigo en el controller

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/views/consulta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redireccionaConsultaPage(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(Constantes.CONSULTA_FORM, new Consulta());
        return Constantes.CONSULTA_VISTA;
}
```

Hice una clase Consulta, la cual contiene los atributos que recupero del formulario entre ellos nombrePago y direccPago, 
y se lo pase como parametro al   model.addAttribute(), 
tambien le pase un string llamado "consulta" que es el nombre que pongo en el atributo modelAttribute de mi formulario, solo que lo meti en una constante, solo que no entiendo aun para que sirve eso?
Ahora, si yo quiero pintar en consola esos datos que recupero del formulario, como le hago?
tendria que hacer otro metodo?
es que quiero ver esos datos en consola y ademas ya que tenga yo esos atributos, los quiero pasar como parametro a un metodo para hacer un query y hacer el filtro con esos datos
apenas empiezo con spring y no se muy bien
como recupero esos datos?

este es mi formulario

```html
<form: form id="consulta" modelAttribute="consulta">
  <tr>
    <td><label>CENTRO PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="pago" path="nombrePago"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td><label>DIRECC PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="direccpago" path="direccPago"/></td>
   </tr>


</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El modelAttribute es una propiedad que referencia a tu objeto dentro de la vista hacia el controlador. Por otra parte, en el código `model.addAttribute(Constantes.CONSULTA_FORM, new Consulta());`, en el primer parámetro pasas el `AttirbuteName` asignado en tu JSP es decir esta parte del inicio de tu formulario `modelAttribute="consulta"`, y en el segundo parámetro le pasas el objeto o `AttributeValue` que va a contener los datos que pasarás por tu formulario (cabe aclarar que también tiene la funcionalidad de pasarle datos y reproducirlos en tu formulario). Entonces para que quede más claro tu método controlador quedaría así:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/views/consulta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redireccionaConsultaPage(Consulta consulta, Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("consulta", consulta);
        System.out.println(consulta.toString()); //Esta sería una forma de mostrar por consola. Puedes manipulas los datos con los get de tu Clase.
        return Constantes.CONSULTA_VISTA;
}
```

> Te dejo este link, de SO donde explican sobre esta propiedad:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc

Para ir finalizando no sé si ya lo investigaste pero quiero aclarar este parámetro en el JSP, en la parte de los input, el parámetro `path` hará referencia a las variables de tu objeto, es decir, en este caso a las variables creadas en la clase Consulta.

```
<form:form method="GET" id="consulta" modelAttribute="consulta">
  <tr>
    <td> <label>CENTRO PAGO</label> </td>
    <td> <form:input type="text" id="pago" path="nombrePago" /> </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td> <label>DIRECC PAGO</label></td>
    <td> <form:input type="text" id="direccpago" path="direccPago" /> </td>
   </tr>
</form:form> <%-- Falto cerrar el formulario --%>
```

> Te dejo también el link de Spring Framework Reference Documentation
>   4.3.18.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:
>   https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.18.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

Espero te ayude.

Comment: gracias por la explicacion, quiero recuperar esos datos al hacer click en un boton, pero como hago que al hacer click, mande a llamar al metodo de mi controller?, gracias